# submit selected data to table php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, pdo

```
$sql = 'SELECT a.guest_id, g.fname, g.lname, g.ph1, g.email, g.arrpickup, g.arrdropoff,  a.approxtime, a.vehicle_id1, a.vehicle_id2, a.vehicle_id3,FROM arrivals a INNER JOIN guest g ON a.guest_id = g.guest_id WHERE g.guest_id = 18';
```

with this I am getting data from the database using inner join.

```
$html = null;
                $html .= '<select>
                  <option value="-1"> ----Select Vehicle---- </option>';

                 $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM vehicle ORDER BY vehicle_id ASC';
                 foreach ($pdo->query($sql1) as $row1) {
                          $html .= '<option value="">'. $row1['model'] . ' - ' . $row1['licplate'] . ' </option>';
                 }
                $html .= '</select>';
```

this is drop down mechanism for getting data from table
its showing using

```
echo  '<tr><td>Vegicle 1</td><td>'.$html.'</td></tr>';
```

now I want to store selected value to table so where to put insert query ? all connection stuff again ?

Comment: well of course you needed to be connected before making an insertion :) and reminder always user prepared statements

Comment: That why you should always seperate logic from template. This is way too messy..

Answer (score 0):

```
$upd_row['your value'];
```

change your get table value in inert a database.
and follow this code and some changes your requerment.
i hope help in your code.

```
$idproduct= "select * from `country_master`";
$str = mysql_query($idproduct);             
$select="";
$issel = '';
if(mysql_num_rows($str)>0)
{   
    while($viewrow=mysql_fetch_array($str))
    {
        if($upd_row['your value'] == $viewrow['id']) 
        {
            $select = "selected";
            $issel = 'yes';
        }else
            $select ="";
        $opts .= "<option value='".$viewrow['id']."'".$select." >".$viewrow['country_name']."</option>";
    }
}
if($issel == '')
    $opts = '<option value="" selected>--Select--</option>'.$opts;
else
    $opts = '<option value="" >--Select--</option>'.$opts;

 echo $opts;
```

?>